# How to send a chatlog of all written chats to a newly joined client using socket programming in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, server, udp, client

I have written a simple server and client py using UDP. The base is working, however I want that every time a user (client) joins, he would receive a chatlog of everything that has been said.

This is my code until now:

Server:

```
import socket
import threading
import queue
import pickle

messages = queue.Queue()
clients = []

# AF_INET used for IPv4
# SOCK_DGRAM used for UDP protocol

ip = "localhost"
port = 5555
chatlog=[]
UDPServerSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# binding IP and port

UDPServerSocket.bind((ip, port))


def receive():
    while True:
        try:
            message, addr = UDPServerSocket.recvfrom(1024)
            messages.put((message, addr))
            chatlog.append((message,addr))
        except:
            pass


def broadcast():
    while True:
        while not messages.empty():
            message, addr = messages.get()
            print(message.decode())
            if addr not in clients:
                clients.append(addr)
            for client in clients:
                try:
                    if message.decode().startswith("SIGNUP_TAG:"):
                        name = message.decode()[message.decode().index(":") + 1:]
                        UDPServerSocket.sendto(f"{name} joined!".encode(), client)
                        if len(chatlog)>0:
                            sending= pickle.dumps(chatlog)
                            UDPServerSocket.sendto(sending, client)
                        else:
                            pass
                    else:
                        UDPServerSocket.sendto(message, client)
                except:
                    clients.remove(client)


t1 = threading.Thread(target=receive)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=broadcast)

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

And the client

```
import socket
import threading
import random

client= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
client.bind(("localhost", random.randint(7000, 8000))) # random port for every client


name =  "Henk" #test name

def receive():
    while True:
        try:
            message, _ = client.recvfrom(1024)
            print(message.decode())
        except:
            pass

t= threading.Thread(target= receive)
t.start()

#this gives the server the name of the people who have entered the server
client.sendto(f"SIGNUP_TAG: {name}".encode(), ("localhost", 5555))

while True:
    message= input("")
    if message=="!q":
        exit()
    else:
        client.sendto(f'[{name}]: {message}'.encode(), ("localhost",5555))
```

So I am actually a bit stuck on how I will approach this. Shall create a text file where every time that a message is written it gets written on the file as well? Or shall I create some kind of string list/database where every message is stored :/

Comment: UDP has a maximum packet size and is usually a bit less then 64K.  If the chatlog is too long pickling your entire chatlog will fail.

Comment: Aha thanks good know, so the log needs to be cleared after some to prevent this.

Comment: Actually, with your `recvfrom(1024)` any message would truncate at 1024 bytes.  I'd just resend the chatlog as individual messages and skip pickling.  Any message received would be no longer than 1024.

Comment: Okay, but I need still to save the messages somewhere right?